# За сколько обращений к БД SQLite выполнится запрос

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть запрос (а точнее несколько) на обновление вида:

```
UPDATE 'таблица' WHERE ...
UPDATE 'таблица' WHERE ...
UPDATE 'таблица' WHERE ...
UPDATE 'таблица' WHERE ...
UPDATE 'таблица' WHERE ...
```

За сколько обращений к БД выполниться запрос, если я подам одной строкой все вышеприведённые запросы? У SQLite, на сколько я знаю, каждый запрос сопровождается транзакциями (блокировка до и блокировка после запроса), а что выйдет в данной ситуации, выйдет ли за раз вставить все эти записи без лишних транзакций?

Comment: Обычно для этого делают параметрические запросы.

Comment: За много обращений в любом случае. При желании можно попробовать объединить в один запрос, но вот нужно ли это и даст ли это хоть сколько нибудь заметный выигрыш это еще вопрос

Comment: @Mike, я вот сейчас над этим думаю, но не знание SQL не сильно этому способствует...

Comment: @Mike, добавьте в ответ, что за много обращений.

Comment: Может проще использовать явные транзакции, а не городить костыли?

Comment: Назовите вашу конечную цель. Если надо выполнить эти действия в одной транзакции, так и выполняйте их в одной, явно ее начав и явно закончив. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html  Или вы это хотите по некой другой причине. В один запрос собрать то можно, но он слишком мудреный выходит, не стоит оно того

Comment: @Mike, я это попробую сделать,  только методом ORMlite — http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#callBatchTasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном контексте 5 запросов.
Но если Вы изменяете данные одного типа то можно сделать один запрос, например UPDATE table SET active=1 WHERE id IN(1,5,8,9), тогда будет один запрос.

Comment: Значения-то разные...